# Using a while loop to compute the sum of integers from two numbers

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with a homework problem on MyPytutor which is asking me to write a function sum_from_to(start, end) that uses a while loop to compute the sum of the integers from start up to, but not including end.

The given code is:

```
def sum_from_to(start, end):
"""Return the sum of the integers from start up to but not including end.

sum_from_to(int, int) -> int
"""
# add your code here: use a while loop
```

Examples:

- sum_from_to(3, 7) should evaluate to 18 (i.e. 3+4+5+6).
- sum_from_to(3, 3) should evaluate to 0.

How would I approach this? I've seen this same question from half a year ago but it was never resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm really stuck on this!

Comment: You expect us to do your homework?

Comment: Do you *have* to use a loop? There is a simple mathematical solution to this that doesn't involve any loops at all, just a simple expression.

Comment: Note that using a while (or for) loop is unnecessarily slow for all but trivial cases, since there's a formula for the sum from 1 to n: `n(n+1)/2`. To find the sum from start to end-1, just calculate for two cases: the sum from 1 to end-1 and the sum from 1 to start-1, and then subtract the latter from the former.

Comment: This is a homework and you just want us to do it? What have you tried? Where did you got stucked in your solution?

Answer (score 4):

Initialize a while loop between [start, end[ (with end excluded with this sign : "<")
Then iterate on the start number.
So for 3 to 7 the numbers will be : 3,4,5,6
Then you just have to add this numbers, so just initialize a var befor your while loop and add this var with the number you iterate

```
def sum_from_to(start, end):
    """Return the sum of the integers from start up to but not including end.

    sum_from_to(int, int) -> int
    """
    result = 0
    i = start
    while i < end:
        result += i
        i += 1
    return result
```

Comment: Can you please expand on why/how this solution answers the question?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples to get you started

```
a = 0
while a < 10:
    a += 1
    print a
```

You could probably do it with

```
sum(range(start, end))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd delivery this:

```
def sum_from_to(start, end):
    ret = 0
    while start < end:
        ret += start
        start += 1
    return ret
```

But I like the way it looks below (without the while - which doesn't fit your requirements):

```
def sum_from_to(start, end):
    return sum(x for x in range(start, end))
```